# Binding QList<Type*> to QListView

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qlistview, qlist

I have a custom type, called `Patients` (please ignore the plural mistake). I want to create a `QList<Patients*>` in my cpp and consume that from my QML. I am following the patterns from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html), but it is not working.

Here is my patients.h (probably more info than needed) . . .

```
class Patients : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ getName)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString email READ getEmail)
    Q_PROPERTY(int id READ getId)

public:
    explicit Patients(QObject *parent = 0);
    explicit Patients(int id, QString name, QString email, QObject *parent = 0);

    QString getName() const;
    QString getEmail() const;
    int getId() const;

private:
    QString email, name;
    int id;
};
```

Here is the main cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QList<Patients*> lst;
    lst.append(new Patients(0, QString("abe"), QString("albert")));
    QQmlContext *ctx = engine.rootContext();
    ctx->setContextProperty("pLst", QVariant::fromValue(lst));

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is the qml . . .

```
ListView{
    id: lst
    height: 100; width: 100
    anchors.fill: parent
    x: 100; y: 100

    model: pLst
    delegate: Text{
        text: model.modelData.name
    }
}
```

It works when I bind a single object, but not as a list. Even presenting the `index` inside `Text` does not work. No error messages or anything.

Comment: Please, I would like to know what was wrong with the editing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no general support for the `QList` container in QML even if the type it is holding is registered to Qt's meta system. Some special variants (e.g. `QStringList` `QList<QObject*>`) are supported by default so you can use `QList<QObject*>` if your class is derived from `QObject`.

If your type is not derived from `QObject` or if you want to keep your interface in C++ clean and typesafe I suggest to use [`QQmlListProperty`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html).   Mind that you don't have to implement the `append()` or `clear()` method if you do not want to make the list modifiable from inside QML.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I must declare the list as

```
QList<QObject*> lst;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will define new class with `QQmlListProperty`, and define a container data object(this class will inherit from `QObject`), in the class of `QQmlListProperty` you will define the container `QList` of pointers of `QObject`. I wrote two posts about this topic:

[Show, change data and keep QQmlListProperty in qml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966474/show-change-data-and-keep-qqmllistproperty-in-qml)

[Use QQmlListProperty to show and modify QList in Qml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284547/use-qqmllistproperty-to-show-and-modify-qlist-in-qml)